# Sum of exponential inequality using MVT

Tags: inequality

I need to prove that $e^x-e^z+e^y-e^z\geq0$ with $x\leq z\leq y<0.$

Can I do the following:

According to the MVT

$e^x-e^z=\epsilon_1(x-z)$, $e^y-e^z=\epsilon_2(y-z)$ with $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2<0.$

Can I say that $\epsilon_1<\epsilon_2$ and then

$e^x-e^z+e^y-e^z=\epsilon_1(x-z)+\epsilon_1(x-z)\geq \epsilon_1(x+y-2z)$

and then try to show that $x+y-2z<0$

Comment: If  $x< z = y$ then $e^x-e^z+e^y-e^z = e^x - e^z < 0$.

Comment: Thanks and the $\epsilon$'s inequality is it correct?